# On the Weakness of Smoothness on a Point?

Tags: analysis

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n-\{0\})$ and $\chi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\chi=1$ in a neighbourhood of $0$. One might show the function: $$g(x):=(1-\chi(x))f(x),$$ is smooth on $\mathbb R^n$.

I started to think about the need of the condition $\chi=1$ in a neighborhood of $0$. I got to the conlusion it is necessary. For example, the function \begin{align*}
\displaystyle \chi(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
e\cdot \exp\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right)&\textrm{se}&|x|<1\\
0&\textrm{se}&|x|\geq 1
\end{array}\right.,
\end{align*}
is an element of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $\chi(0)=1$ and if $$a(x)=\|x\|_2$$ then $a\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n-\{0\})$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm, but $$g(x)=(1-\chi(x))\|x\|_2,$$ is not smooth in $\mathbb R^n$.

Why the condition $\chi(0)=1$ is not enough to ensure $g$ whereas $\chi=1$ is a neighborhood of $0$ suffices?

Thanks.

**Notation:** $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is the set of all smooth function on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact support.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you multiply a function by something that is *flat* on a whole open set, then the result is a constant function on that set, and hence smooth.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I rewrote the question, I guess it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\chi(0)=1$ is not enough because the fact that $1-\chi$ vanishes at $0$ is not enough to correct every possible thing that could be wrong with $f$ near $0$. Examples are easy to come by: take $\chi(x)=1-\|x\|^2$ and $f(x) = \|x\|^{-4}$; clearly, $g$ is not even bounded near $0$.

Another example is $f(x)=\sin(\|x\|^{-4})$. Now $g$ is continuous, but its derivative is not: it blows up near $0$. (You may want to do the computation in the one-dimensional case, for simplicity.)

On  the other hand, having $\chi=1$ in a neighborhood of $0$ is  sure way to eliminate whatever bad behavior   $f(x)$ has as $x$ approaches $0$. Indeed, the product is identically $0$ in a neighborhood of $0$, which certainly makes it smooth there. Elsewhere, both factors in the product are smooth.

*Summary*: if a function is $0$ at a  point, it need not be smooth (or even differentiable, or continuous) at that point. But if it is $0$ in a neighborhood of that point, it is smooth there.